# I've get a resultset by python BeautifulSoup, but I don't know how to fetch the NavigableString inside them

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
html_text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
get_details = soup.find_all('li', attrs={"class":"news"})
# get_details is an aggregation of results fetched by BeautifulSoup find_all() method
```

one instance of the resultset is as below:

```
<li class="news">blah blah blah what i want blah blah blah  <a href="/graphic/graphicInfoData/000002230030421305">View details</a></li>
```

What I want is the "blah blah blah what i want blah blah blah", the so-called Navigable string in BeautifulSoup. But I can not use .string attribute to a list, even when I use the print(get_details[0].string), the result is None, why?

by the way , as a comparison,  below code works!

```
print(get_details[0].a.string)
>>> print(get_details[0].li.string)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
    print(get_details[0].li.string)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.get_text()` instead of `.string`:

```
print(get_details[0].a.get_text())
```

Output: `View details`

```
print(get_details[0].get_text())
```

Output: `blah blah blah what i want blah blah blah  View details`

Be aware, that `get_details[0].get_text()` will get all the text of the `li`.

Following will only get the first part:

```
get_details[0].contents[0].strip()
```

Output: `blah blah blah what i want blah blah blah`

Comment: wow, thanks very much! So fast and exact the answer it is. this made me a big fan of stackoverflow, I'm new here. Gorgeous community! big hug @HedgeHog

Comment: You got it. New hand.awkward.